# Ranorex Passing Array as Parameter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ranorex

I have some calculations to complete.  I want to send my array to a method that does some calculations.  How do I format the sending method here?  How do I format the receiving signature line of the receipient method?  How do I split the array to use each element?

```
public void PercentCompare()
{
    string[] cells = {
          "Repo.Path.ToString()", 
          "Repo.Path.ToString()", 
          "Repo.Path.ToString()"
       };

    Path.CountDoublePercent(cells[]);
}

public static void CountD(string[] cells)
{
    //trims
    string trimRow1 = string.Empty; 
    string trimRow2 = string.Empty;
    string trimTotal = string.Empty; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ranorex.com/forum/passing-array-as-usercode-argument-t8098.html

this site says: it’s not possible to use an array as an argument for UserCode methods

Can you really do it with no errors?